# Подключение статической библиотеки

Tags: c, lib

В .h файле моей программы инициализирована структура.

 Мне нужно использовать статическую библиотеку вместо него.
Я в Visual Studio скомпилировал статическую библиотеку, где вызываю лишь хедер.
Проблема в том, что мне не удается подключить ее к своей программе.
Я пытался сделать это с помощью добавления этого: `(#pragma comment ( lib, "MathFuncsLib.lib" ))` в свойства Студии (Компоновщик -> Ввод -> Дополнительные зависимости), но мне это не помогло.

Я получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "#pragma comment ( lib,
>   \MathFuncsLib.lib\ ).obj

Если туда же добавить лишь MathFuncsLib.lib, то компиляция крашится, но не из-за кривого вызова библиотеки, а из-за отсутствия определения структуры.

 Не подскажите, как это пофиксить? Спасибо.

Comment: *компилируется нормально, но ничего не происходит* - Простите, а что вы ожидаете? Что должно произойти?

Comment: Оговорился.
Подключение стат. библиотеки должно заменить вызов хедера.

Comment: А компиляция крашится, но не из-за кривого вызова библиотеки, а из-за отсутствия определения структуры.

Comment: Вы, по-моему, несколько путаетесь. Немного упрощенно - в заголовочном файле находятся всяческие объявления, тех же типов структур и т.п. А в библиотеке в первую очередь - тела функций, ну, глобальные переменные. Когда вы включаете <stdio.h>, то вы берете объявление какой-нибудь `printf` оттуда, но ее код - из соответствующей библиотеки. И одно другим *не заменяется*. Вам все равно нужен заголовочный файл, в котором описываются типы данных, объявления функций и т.п. А в библиотеке - готовый *скомпилированный* код этих функций, для работы с этими типами.

Comment: Я понимаю это.
Но в задании указано это:
Дополнить реализацию лабораторной работы таким образом, чтобы описание структур данных и функциональности из предметной области находились в статически подключаемой библиотеке.

Comment: Возможно, я просто не понял, что от меня требуют в задании.

Comment: Вот именно "функциональность из предметной области" и пойдет в библиотеку. "Описание структур данных" (внешние)  останутся в заголовочном файле. Ваше задание никак не предполагает какой-то взаимоисключающей "замены" заголовочного файла библиотекой. Не ясно, откуда у вас возникла такая интерпретация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Во-первых, подключение библиотеки никак не может *заменить* включение заголовочного файла. Нужно и то, и то. То есть ни о каком "использовать статическую библиотеку *вместо* него" не может быть и речи.
- Во-вторых, в библиотеке не может содержаться "лишь хедер". Традиционный хедер не содержит объектного кода или вообще каких-то материальных сущностей. Поэтому и библиотеку из него сделать не получится.
- В-третьих, при подключении библиотек через `#pragma comment`, этот `#pragma comment(lib, "MathFuncsLib.lib")` надо добавлять не в "свойства Студии" (откуда у вас возникла такая идея?), а прямо в исходный текст вашей программы. В этом вся суть `#pragma comment`.

  Но обычно библиотеки подключают через настройки линкера, а не через `#pragma comment`. Если же вы хотите идти по этому традиционному пути, то это делается через свойства проекта (не Студии, а именно вашего проекта). В настройки линкера надо добавить просто `MathFuncsLib.lib`.

  Разумеется, необходимо еще, чтобы линкер знал, где искать этот `MathFuncsLib.lib`, т.е. надо либо положить `MathFuncsLib.lib` в правильное место, либо прописать правильные пути в настройках линкера, либо указать полный путь к `MathFuncsLib.lib`.